# Add Controls to an inherited Form c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

I created two forms:

1. FormBase
2. FormChild

FormBase contains a panelMain and two buttons (buttonOk and buttonCancel) which are added to the panelMain.

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.buttonCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.buttonOk = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panelMain = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.panelMain.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // buttonCancel
        // 
        this.buttonCancel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.buttonCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(465, 208);
        this.buttonCancel.Name = "buttonCancel";
        this.buttonCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 42);
        this.buttonCancel.TabIndex = 0;
        this.buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        this.buttonCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // buttonOk
        // 
        this.buttonOk.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.buttonOk.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(352, 208);
        this.buttonOk.Name = "buttonOk";
        this.buttonOk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 42);
        this.buttonOk.TabIndex = 1;
        this.buttonOk.Text = "Ok";
        this.buttonOk.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // panelMain
        // 
        this.panelMain.Controls.Add(this.buttonOk);
        this.panelMain.Controls.Add(this.buttonCancel);
        this.panelMain.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.panelMain.Name = "panelMain";
        this.panelMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(584, 262);
        this.panelMain.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // FormBase
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(584, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panelMain);
        this.Name = "FormBase";
        this.Text = "FormBase";
        this.panelMain.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    internal System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonCancel;
    internal System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonOk;
    public System.Windows.Forms.Panel panelMain;
```

Now I want to inherit FormBase to FormChild.

```
    public partial class FormChild : FormBase
```

When the FormChild is resized in the FormChild.cs[Designer] the two buttons stay at the bottom-right end of FormChild.

My problem is that when I add a label to the panelMain in the **FormChild.cs[Design]** and the FormChild is resized now, the two buttons don´t stay at the bottom-right end of FormChild, instead they always remain at the default location defined in FormBase.

```
this.buttonCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(465, 208);
this.buttonOk.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(352, 208);
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Anchors don't work well in a inheritance scenario, the control anchors to the original client size, not the new size.  How much SuspendLayout() affects that isn't clear to me, but there isn't anything you can do about it anyway.  I *think* the only practical solution is to either apply Anchor in the derived class or not change the size until the Load event fires.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Then I will try to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you add a control (it does not matter what sort) or resize the form in design view, the Designer adds the following line to the FormChild.Designer.cs:

```
this.panelMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(xxx, yyy);
```

Simply delete this line, and your form should work as you expect.